# Custom Text column for DataDridView with DropDown list but no validation

Tags: winforms, datagridview

The DataGridViewComboBoxColumn implements a DropDownList functionality, which validates the data against the values in the list.

I want to implement a custom column which behaves like a ComboBox with DropDown functionality, which does not validate the data against the list.

Is there a way to create a custom column which:

- inherits from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
- changes the DropDownStyle property of editing control to ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
- disables cell validation against the items in the list

Does anybody have sample code with this behavior?

Comment: You can implement your own `ComboBox` column. Also you can simply use the `TextBox` auto complete feature.

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei. (1) I've implemented my own column based on DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and cell based on DataGridViewTextBoxCell. I override the EditType property (in the cell) and specify DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl. I override InitializeEditingControl to initialize the ComboBox. (2) If I inherit from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn I get validation which I don't want. I haven't figured out how to override this. (3) I have also found the AutoComplete function. In fact it is probably the best solution for my application (based on a text box not a combobox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried several solutions and settled on using a standard text box column and enabling the AutoComplete feature. I am not using a custom column.

During initialization, I create an AutoCompleteStringCollection containing the elements for the dropdown list

```
private AutoCompleteStringCollection _SerialNumbers ;
```

I attach to the EditingControlShowing event, check that it is the right column and enable AutoComplete.

```
private void dgvChannels_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  if ( dgvChannels.CurrentCell.OwningColumn == SerialNumber )
  {
    TextBox c = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (c != null)
    {
      c.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
      c.AutoCompleteCustomSource = _SerialNumbers;
      c.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }
  }
}
```

Functionally, a text box with AutoComplete is very similar to a Combobox with DropDown style. In my case, the functionality is actually better.

Weirdly, you can also use AutoComplete on a ComboBox, which can result in there being two drop lists at the same time. That's some user experience!